# Фильтрация по размеру пакета

Tags: c++, pcap

Доброго времени суток!
Никак не могу понять, как отфильтровать трафик в winpcap по размеру пакета. (в моем случае убрать пакеты, у которых размер не равен задаваемому)
PS: фильтр обманчиво говорит, что успешно поставился, но на деле это не так.
PPS: с многими другими фильтрами всё нормально работает, а с размером так и не удалось побаловаться.

```
packetFilterStr = " len  != " + sizePacket;
pcap_compile(traffic, &fp, const_cast<char*>(packetFilterStr.c_str()), 1, 0xffffff);
pcap_setfilter(traffic, &fp);
```

Спасибо за помощь!